# Load table from hbase to hdfs through map-reduce program

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

How to write a map-reduce program to load any table from hbase into hdfs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways :-

1. Use the Hbase's TableMapreduceUtil (  http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.html) where you can specify a table scan and them manipulate data or write it to hdfs.
2. You can use hbase's utility which creates a snapshot of the whole hbase table into hdfs called export ( http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export), the *import* tool can be used to load the backed up table from hdfs to hbase.